# Ensuring conceptual integrity in Python project with multiple programmers

Tags: design, python

One objection that I have *often* heard raised against Python that it is difficult to synchronize a team of many programmers on large Python project. Note: that synchronization is *possible* in such a project does not necessarily entail that it is practical, cheap or easy. There's still n*(n-1) communication channels between programmers, so communication cost grows more or less with square of number of programmers, on average.

One thing I liked in Java are interfaces. Sadly, both PEP 245 and even modified Guido's version on interfaces ( http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=87182 ) have not been implemented. I was thinking that duck-typing style limited interfaces (no types, just method names) might be very useful, emphatically not for sake of pychecker, faster code, or forcing (dumb) programmers to follow (smart) architect's design, but as means of easy synchronization between 2+ programmers.

So, apart from typical but not working very well suggestion of "more documentation" (nobody wants to write it really), what are your means of synchronization high-level design and conceptual integrity on such large, multi-person projects?

(in part I ask because large projects I have participated in never used Python)

<sub>I heard objections mentioned above in person: At least 3 times when talking to startups (2 Scala startups, so they have slant towards static typing) and at least once within corp when considering various programming languages for projects. On the web: can't remember this now, I have vague memory of reading it on some OO blogs and forums. Static typing guys (Java, Scala) seem to have had big on this point, even though typically static typing and interfaces are usually meant for other things (speed, IDE autocompletion).</sub>

<sub>Note I know [TDD](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/tdd/info) defense on this but the problem here is that it is defensive since typically it's one person that writes unit tests. Of course, one could envision 1+ programmers sitting down together and writing unit tests before coding as sort of indirect spec + test but have you seen it done? I haven't.  I also feel that unit tests, even written by groups, are not quite (limited) design or spec. They are low level after all. There's a reason (good maybe?) that Java has interfaces in addition to and not instead of JUnit.</sub>

Comment: could you please give example(s) where you've seen "objection" you mention? also per my recollection of Eckel's article _[Why I love Python](http://www.mindviewinc.com/downloads/pub/eckel/LovePython)_, the solution for issues like that is considered not "more documentation" but rather more tests

Comment: In person: At least 3 times when talking to startups (2 Scala startups, so they have slant towards static typing) and at least once within corp when considering various programming languages for projects. On the web: can't remember this now, I have vague memory of reading it on some OO blogs and forums. Static typing guys (Java, Scala) seem to have been big on this point in my experience (YMMV of course), even though typically static typing and interfaces are usually meant for other things (speed, IDE autocompletion).

Comment: Yes I know TDD defense but the problem here is that it is defensive since typically it's one person that writes unit tests. Of course, one could envision 1+ programmers sitting down together and writing unit tests before coding as sort of indirect spec + test but have you seen it done? I haven't.

Comment: @gnat: I also feel that unit tests, even written by groups, are not quite (limited) design or spec. They are low level after all and verify details mainly (that's the purpose I think, perhaps I'm in error on this). There's a reason (good maybe?) that Java has interfaces in addition to and not instead of JUnit.

Comment: I feel your feeling is not quite correct. I for one participated in a project that had specification expressed in form of tests - it was as formal and official as it gets. Actually my experience there was that if one can't afford qualified spec-writer, expressing it through tests is a viable (though slightly inferior) alternative

Comment: @gnat: I very much would like my view on this (unit tests as sort of spec) not to be correct as I'd prefer working in Python to working in Java. :-) However, there are a few issues: 1. how big was the project you mention? My current project has about 40 people (20 developers, 20 testers). Would it be practical to scale that big in Python using TDD as spec only? 2. subteams dispersed geographically - now we have 4 teams in Europe and 1 team in California (just beginning the transition so it's too early to tell how it will work). Would unit tests work in this setup?

Comment: Note that you *can* use interfaces in Python. `zope.interface` provides exactly that. The interfaces are not *enforced* but you *can* verify them in unit tests. I don't believe that the problem you talk about exists though.

Comment: And if it is 'typically one person that writes unit tests' then you are doing it wrong. *Every* developer needs to write unit tests.

Comment: gnat's link points to a Zip file with no filename. Just `mv mv LovePython LovePython.zip` to get to the zipped powerpoint presentation, which LibreOffice seems to display just fine.

Comment: @mrkafk can't tell; there were 4-5 companies involved and they didn't tell their amount of dev/QA. Spec group was 15-20 members if memory serves; it was distributed globally. Functionality was rather compact though - under 100 use cases iirc

Comment: @MartijnPieters: well that's what I meant, if not phrased very well: that a developer tends to write unit tests for his code only, and in isolation from other developers (every developer here writes unit tests, but it's not team activity).

Comment: @gnat: thanks! hmm that's still quite sizable project.. I wonder what's going on much with this, as one of those Scala startups moved from Python to Scala precisely bc of experience of one of programmers with Python, that is, he could not sync his Python code with code of another Python programmer - then again, I got the impression (not confirmed out in the open though) that their integration was not quite continuous but more intermittent or spotty. Perhaps that was the source of the problem, I could not really dig deeper for other reasons.

Comment: @mrkafk: what you are looking for is integration and functional tests. Those verify that the various components work together, and these tests tend to span the work of various developers anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: re zope.interface (thanks!), a vague realization I had too was to make some classes "culturally untouchable" by declaring them that "those are top-level DESIGN classes, don't mess with them unless you have a good reason". I'm not saying this is a good idea, but you could I think get many people to treat them AS IF they were interfaces. Python bytecode compiler would not protest but if tests or dev lead detected that they could sort of slap wrists around, essentially getting similar *human behavior* to how Java interfaces seem to affect people's mind/behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like GlenH7's answer, and I believe there is truth there.

However, my perspective is that the answer to your problems is Code Ownership.

If five large teams are re-using the same model classes, and want to pile on unnecessary crap into them, then the only way out is to say "Team X owns this code, if you want to change it talk to them". Or, "John owns this code, if you want to change it talk to him."

You still need communication, but the nature of it changes. The assumption is that your request for change will be shot down unless there is a very good reason to put it in. Also, this creates a decision making body with final say, rather than co-owned code being modified by a 'design committee' (which frequently leads to either chaos or analysis paralysis).

Consider this also: there is nothing magical about Java interfaces. They give some design hints from the (hopefully smart) architect, but they don't protect against someone who needs a quick hack from going in there and changing your interfaces anyway. The only thing that really protects from that is code control, code ownership, and some degree of personal responsibility.

So if you're facing "interface" madness, designate responsible people for it and allocate code ownership. Make sure these people do their jobs.

Comment: Ownership without proper accountability and oversight is a good recipe for endless chaos.  Eisenhower threatened to resign his command if the powers that were would not place the airborne and bombers under his command for the invasion of Europe.

Comment: @gahooa Well that's the idea. Once you own it, you are responsible for it. If everyone owns it, then everyone (no one?) is responsible.

Comment: @suslik: re changing Java interfaces - yeah that's what I wondered too, if somebody wants to mess with a class or even abstract class in Java, why not mess with interface too? :-) Technologically there is no barrier to do it: however, the way people TREAT interfaces is as if they were sort of holy cows: theoretically you could slaughter it, but... they feel sort of "sacred", put above mere classes where you work all the time. Interfaces in Java are treated - for purely psychological and cultural reasons I think - as sort of "medium level design". At least that's my experience.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're focusing too much on the language that you are using and not the real challenge that's facing you and your team.  Remember that there aren't any silver bullets.

Ultimately, your problem is governance.  As governance is really the only way to `ensure conceptual integrity` for any project.

The need for governance follows either a linear or exponential path correlated to the size of the team.  When you add in geographic and cultural divides, you're simply piling on to the need for governance.

There are some simple ways to get started.

If no one wants to write a whole bunch of documentation, then make sure code is commented liberally and correctly.  Avoid littering with your comments, but make sure others understand the contracts that each section of code is fulfilling.

If you don't want others accessing particular parts of code and you can't encapsulate it, then you should be putting comments around those areas to indicate what can and can't be used.  Even if the language doesn't directly support it, you can still mock up interfaces and closed objects within the code.  FWIW, I've written OO style code in C.  It *can* be done.

One of the ways you enforce that encapsulation is code review.  The tribal elders from each team needs to review all new code before it's allowed into the build.  If you have an architect, then they need to be in constant communication with the tribal elders to make sure they understand the vision and that everyone is in agreement with how the project will be built.

Management has to back the architect and the elders at the first skirmish.  Someone is going to break the rules and insist it goes in because you're behind the deadline.  Don't do it.  Politely slap the violator's wrist; force them to fix the code; then allow the commit.  Management has to back missing the deadline to guarantee the integrity of the project.  Yes, you missed a deadline but you have to focus on the long term goal.

As mentioned in the comments; everyone should be writing unit tests for their code.  Assigning that task to a single person is setting the project up for failure.  Use those tests to enforce the encapsulation and rules needed to stabilize your project.  If new code doesn't have a unit test then don't allow the requirement to be marked complete.

Ensuring the integrity of a project is everyone's responsibility with each tier taking on differing aspects based upon their own job function.

Comment: @Glen7: I like your answer a lot actually but it is wider re good project management (it should be pinned up on pm stackexchange somewhere I think - is there a wiki here or smth?). Code ownership seems narrower issue here and it just happens to be particularly severe problem area for my team (more so than other areas from my POV) so I'm marking suslik's answer below.

Comment: @mrkafk - thanks for the update.  Always feel free to select the answer that best applies / fits to you.  It's _your_ question, so it's _your_ choice for marking as answered.